# Mail Functionality Headers Issues in PHP

Tags: php

I am using the following code for mail headers. But it doesn't work properly:

```
$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($mailfrom) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($mailfrom) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";`
```

without using the following lines mails are send successfully with html tags:

```
$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($mailfrom) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($mailfrom) . "\r\n";
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: No error shehary.. mail not send to mail Id. i have remove the following code                                                                                                          ` $headers =  "From: " . strip_tags($mailfrom) . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($mailfrom) . "\r\n"; ` . Mail Are send but receiving with html tags

Comment: If the code works without those headers, I'm going to guess that the emails you're sending are getting filtered out as spam. With the headers added, you're sending HTML, changing the From header and adding a different email as a Reply-to, all of which looks very spammish. There's no easy solution, but you can look into things like setting SPF records to make your emails look more legitimate.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .='From: '.$mailfrom . "\r\n";
$headers .='Reply-To: '.$mailfrom . "\r\n";
```

Comment: Can you post a received mail.

Comment: Sending Mail Failed Sir. then how to post a received mail?

Comment: You mentioned above you you received mail with HTML tags. Can you post your code in here. We can help you better then :)